# facebook extended permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have created a sample test app in developers.facebook.com to access notifications for a facebook account in my WebApplication.
When i try to get the accesstoken by navigating to this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="+clientId+"&redirect_uri="+redirectURI+"&scope=manage_notifications
```

from my facebook account for the first time i get oauth dialog where in i login with my facebook login-id and password. Then a popup appears telling me that the app requires access to your basic profile details. Then when i click ok i get one more popup asking me to authorize manage_notifications for this app. When i click ok i am redirected to my web application homepage where i can see list of all notifications for my account.

Now when i try to navigate to the above url and at the oauth dialog, if i login with another Facebook Account i get only a popup saying that the app requires access to my basic profile details but not the popup requesting manage_notifications. And when i click ok i am redirected to my webapp homepage. And i get an error message saying i dont have extended permissions - "manage_notifications"

How do i access notifications for any user in my web application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All permissions except

- public_profile
- user_friends
- email

require a review of your app by Facebook before you can use them publically. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: I can't able to birthday from facebook...Do you help me?

Comment: I can't think of any other company that provides an authenticated API that needs to go through your app before allow you to use it...