# How to get friends' birthday from facebook SDK 4.x?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all my friends' birthday after login successfully from my app using fb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get birthdays of friends who authorized your App with the `user_birthday` permission too. You can´t get birthdays of friends who did not authorize your App.

**Also, `user_birthday` needs to get reviewed, or you can only use it as user with a role in the App.**

That being said, here is the API endpoint: `/me/friends?fields=name,birthday`

Comment: i tried but doesn't work , do i have to make app review to get birthday permission ?

Comment: what exactly does not work? are you sure the friends who authorized your app also authorized the correct permission? what api call did you try and what is the exact response?

Comment: I am using  Graph API and the API endpoint: /me/friends?fields=name,birthday , response is all friends who are logged in through my app but without their birthday although when i put these friends in testusers it works :/ . any explanation

Comment: then thei either did not enter their birthday (not sure if that is a requirement) or they did not authorize with the user_birthday permission.

Comment: then i donot have to review my app to use user_birthday permission ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751076/facebook-extended-permission/24753070#24753070

Comment: well, you have to go through review to go public, did you not read the official docs about login review?

Comment: @ luschn so , everyone of my Facebook friends should install my app and approve user_birthday permission so i can access their birthday ?

Comment: exactly, else you can´t get their birthday at all.

Comment: what about posting on friends' wall or send a private message to them ?
thankkks

Comment: what about it? you can´t spam people. that´s not allowed and not possible.

Comment: why not just do that on facebook.com? you really don´t need an app for that. also, please, do some research before asking, there are many threads on stackoverflow about the topic "posting to a friends timeline". answer: it´s not possible, luckily.